# I want to get an input from a user of my app through an edittext and when they press a button, it adds the input into a file stored on the device

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting an error stating that I have an unresolved reference in both places where I try a findViewById though both login_button and username are present in my xml file

```
class LoginPage : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginPageBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)
        val value: String = name.text.toString()
        File("current_users.txt").appendText(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message. Then indicate which line causes the error. Also [edit] your question to include `activity_login_page.xml`.

Comment: Having the exact error message would help

Answer (score 1):

When you use view binding, you don't need to call `findViewById()`. Instead, use the fields that are generated in the `ActivityLoginPageBinding` class. For example, you can do `binding.login_button` if there is an `id:+login_button` and `<Button android:id=@+id/username>` in your XML layout. See [the View Binding guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) for more details.